# 2 properties inside SortExpression

Tags: c#, asp.net

[SOLVED], used Ondrej Svejdar's answer.

I'm using :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created By" SortExpression="User.Firstname">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="User" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("User.Firstname")'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Which shows on my form like this: **Created By Firstname**.

But I want to make it look like this : **Created By Firstname Lastname**. How do I attach another string inside the "SortExpression" and "Text" ?

Comment: What is the problem in adding another string inside sortexpression and text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created By" SortExpression="User.Firstname,User.Lastname">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0} {1}", Eval("User.Firstname"), Eval("User.Lastname")) %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Beware that sorting by multiple columns, may not always give you what you want:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1236912.aspx/1

Comment: Interesting note on the multiple column sorting. That's a very strange bug to have...

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created By" SortExpression="User.Firstname, User.Lastname">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="User" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("User.Firstname") <%#Bind("User.Lastname")'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created By" SortExpression="User.Firstname,User.Lastname">
     <ItemTemplate>    
<asp:Label ID="User" runat="server" Text='<%#(Eval("User.Firstname").ToString()+ " " + Eval("User.Lastname").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>

 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```